# How can I catch error rethrown from async function?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

```
try {
  const promise = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    reject('oe')
  })
  .catch(async (err) => {
    console.log('bbbbb', err)
    throw err
  })
} catch (err) {
  console.log('aaaaa', err)
}
```

Is is possible to make `aaaaa` loggable

Comment: I'm not sure what your intentions but I truly recommended this article.. it helped me a lot understating that topic better (https://blog.grossman.io/how-to-write-async-await-without-try-catch-blocks-in-javascript/)

Comment: You should *never* pass an `async` function as a callback to `new Promise`, `then` or `catch`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, it doesn't make sense to pass an `async` function into a promise's `then` or `catch` function. And it never makes sense to pass one into the promise constructor. If you're going to go `async`, do it earlier. Also, when you want a rejected promise for testing, etc., just use `Promise.reject('oe')`.

In order to catch an error from an `async` function with a `try`/`catch`, you must be in an `async` function. In that case, the minimal change to your example would be to `await` the result of the call to `catch`:

```
// Assuming this is in an `async` function, making only minimal changes
try {
  const promise = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    reject('oe')
  })
  .catch(async (err) => {
    console.log('bbbbb', err)
    throw err
  })
  await promise;  // ***
} catch (err) {
  console.log('aaaaa', err)
}
```

If you aren't in an `async` function, you can't use `try`/`catch` to catch errors from promises (which includes from an `async` function call, since they return promises). Instead, you have to use the promise returned by `catch`:

```
// Assuming this is NOT in an `async` function, making only minimal changes
const promise = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
  reject('oe')
})
.catch(async (err) => {
  console.log('bbbbb', err)
  throw err
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log('aaaaa', err)
})
```

---

Making larger changes, if you're already in an `async` function, get rid of the `then` and `catch` calls:

```
// Assuming this is in an `async` function
try {
  try {
    await Promise.reject('oe');
  } catch (innerError) {
    console.log('bbbbb', innerError);
    throw innerError;
  }
} catch (outerError) {
  console.log('aaaaa', outerError);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your explaination! It is clear to understand, I modified my code not to use await in catch block, instead, I awaited the promises in Promise.all wrapped by try catch block

Answer (score 1):

You can use `async/await`:

```js
async function test() {
  try {
    const promise = await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      reject('oe')
    }).catch(async err => {
      console.log('bbbbb', err)
      throw err
    })
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('aaaaa', err)
  }
}
test()
```